# Expanding Square Roots, Why No Negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, quadratics

I haven't thought through algebra in a while and the last explanation I received of this seemed arbitrary.  I hope I can get some clarification here.

I understand that $\sqrt{+a} = \pm b$.  Here's something I don't however.

Evaluate using FOIL: $(\sqrt{8} - \sqrt{2})(\sqrt{8} - \sqrt{2})$

Evaluation yields: $8 - \sqrt{16} - \sqrt{16} + 2 == 8 - 2\sqrt{16} +2$

In this case, why must $-2\sqrt{16} = 8$ and not $-8$?

Thanks!

Comment: We *always* agree that $\sqrt a$ denotes the **unique positive real number** such that $x^2=a$. Hence $\sqrt{16}=4$.

Comment: To further elaborate on Pedro's comment, you might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/809424/39599) question and its answers helpful.

Comment: Your FOIL got the wrong sign on the last term, it confused me at first how the multiplication of two positive numbers could be negative...

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.  I understand now.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Question is answered in the comments under my original post:

> We *always* agree that $\sqrt a$ denotes the **unique positive real number** such that $x^2=a$. Hence $\sqrt{16}=4$. --  [Pedro Tamaroff](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro-tamaroff)
>
> To further elaborate on Pedro's comment, you might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809424/39599) question and its answers helpful.  -- [Michael Albanese](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39599/michael-albanese)