# Is it wrong to say that $100$ is solution of $\sqrt x+10=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> Is it wrong to say that 100 is solution of $\sqrt x +10=0$?

I know that range of $\sqrt{x}$ is $[0, \infty)$ by convention. This convention is because of definition of a function. So if I consider $\sqrt x+10=0$ as a simple equation then can I say hundred is a solution to the equation?

I think I can say that because if I square both sides I get $x=100$ and also if I consider $\sqrt x+10=0$ just as a equation then there is no need of thinking about functions and the convention of omitting negative roots.

Comment: You can say it because $\sqrt{100} - 10 = 0$.  So 100 is a solution.  That's all there is to it.  Why *wouldn't* you be able to say that.

Comment: @fleablood I think in my original question it was $+$ sign.

Comment: Oh, in that case, no, you *can't* say it $\sqrt{100} + 10 = 20 \ne 0$ so it is not a solution.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: No, yo can't say that

Comment: @fleablood But isn't $(-10)^2 = 100$ ? I get that $10$ is the square root of $100$ by convention, that is because to fit $\sqrt{x}$ in the definition of function but here will it matter if I don't consider $\sqrt{x}$ as a function ?

Comment: Squaring both sides adds extraneous solutions.  $x = 5$ has only one solution.  Squaring both sides $x^2 = 25$ add the extraneous, and wrong, "solution" $x = -5$ which is not a solution.

Comment: If the range of $\sqrt x$ is strictly positive, how can $\sqrt x$ equal a negative number?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The range is positive (not strictly) if it is function. But here in this question it does not matter if I don't consider it to be function right ?

Comment: Of course, but that is totally irrelevant.  $x = 2 \implies x^2 = 4$.  $x^2 = 4$ has two solutions. Squaring both sides does not create an equivalent equation.  It makes a weaker solution.  The solutions to $x = k$ are solutions to $x^2 = k^2$ but the sollutions to $x^2 = k^2$ are not solutions to $x = k$.

Comment: Please see:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809424/can-the-square-root-of-a-real-number-be-negative

Comment: I love to know the reason of the downvote.

Comment: @fleablood I do know that but that is irrelevant here because 100 is a solution to  $\sqrt{x} + 10 = 0$ if we consider its negative root.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, but I don't disagree with the downvote.  Some of the suggested reasons for downvoting: "*The question does not show any research effort; it is not clear or not useful*".  The shortest amount of research into the question of your own will tell you that $\sqrt{x}$ is always positive or zero, and that a positive number plus another positive number is always positive, implying that $\sqrt{100}+10$ is certainly not zero.  We **only** consider the positive root in *any* context that the $\sqrt{~}$ symbol is used, regardless of whether we are calling it a function or not.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think the question was not phrased properly. I get that we dont take negative root but that is because of definition of functions. What should I use if I want to consider both roots ?

Comment: Ah.. But $\sqrt{n}$ is NOT the negative square root.  It is, by DEFINITION, the *positive square root.  $\sqrt{n} = -10$ does NOT mean $(-10)^2 = n$.  It means $(-10)^2 = $ AND $-10 \ge 0$.  Which is simply not true.

Comment: @fleablood Ok then do I have to use $\pm \sqrt{x}$ everywhere if I have to use negative roots as well ?

Comment: Then you want to solve $\pm \sqrt{x} + 10 = 0$.  So $\pm \sqrt{x} = -10$.  $\sqrt{x} =-10$ is simply impossible.  So $-\sqrt{x} = -10$ and $ \sqrt{x} = 10$ and $x = 100$.  So $x = 100$ is a (only) solution to $\pm \sqrt{x} + 10 = 0$.

Comment: Yes you do.  <><>

Comment: @fleablood Well I think something positive come out of this question. I did not know $\sqrt $ stands for +ve roots. I think I can sleep well tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to $f(x) = k$ are a *SUBSET* of the solutions to $f(x)^2 = k^2$ but not all the solution to $f(x)^2 = k^2$ are solutions to $f(x) = k$.  Squaring both sides of an equation add extraneous solutions.

$\sqrt{x} + 10 = 0$

$\sqrt{x} = -10$ Doesn't just mean that $(\sqrt{x}^2 = (-10)^2$.  It ALSO means that $\sqrt{x} = -10 < 0$.

When we square both sides we LOSE information.

$\sqrt{x}^2 = (-10)^2$

$x = 100$ but we have completely *LOST* that $\sqrt{x} < 0$.

Any  $\sqrt{100} + 10 = 10 + 10 = 20 \ne 0$.  SO it simply *DOESN'T* work.

Consider this:

$x =2 $ has one solution. Square both sides and you get $x^2 = 4$.  Which has *TWO* solutions!!!  Where did that solution $x = -2$ come from?

It came because when we squared both sides we added invalid extraneous solutions.

Solutions to $x= 2$ is $\{2\}$.  Solutions to $x^2 = 4$ has solutions $\{2,-2\}$ and $\{2\} \subset \{2,-2\}$.  But it doesn't go the other way.  It only goes one way.

Comment: I think to be precise you need to mention that $\sqrt{x}$ is called *principal square root*, which is non-negative by definition. Please see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation x^2 = 100

When we take the square root of the equation to solve it, we would write

x = ± sqrt(100)

Notice that there is a ± sign in front of the square root. The reason that is there is precisely because sqrt(x) is defined as the principle square root.

So, when you evaluate sqrt(100) + 10, you get 10 + 10 = 20, proving your equation false.

Answer (score 0):

$x=100$ is most definitely a solution to $\sqrt{x}-10=0$, because if you plug $x=100$ into the equation, you get $\sqrt{100}-10=0$, or $10-10=0$, which is true.

Comment: I think the OP changed the + sign to the minus sign, which he must have meant all along.

Comment: @MarkFischler edited accordingly

Comment: @MarkFischler No that was not my edit.

Answer (score -1):

$√(x)+10=0$

$√(x)=-10$

$√(x)^2=(-10)^2$

$x=100$

$√(100)+10≠0$

Thus, since $√(100)+10$ does not equal zero, **this equation has no solution.**