# Justification for the use of principal square root.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

In [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1055698/312097), author uses the principal square root of $1 + \tan^2 x$ to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int {\sec^2 x \over (\sec x + \tan x)^{9/2}}$. Author rewrites $\sec x $ as $\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 x}$ and proceeds with it.

Since secant of an angle can be negative in second and third quadrant, I want to know why does using principal square root is justified here ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean to ask? Clearly $1+tan^2x$ is $sec^2x$ and root of it is $+-secx$ isn't it?

Comment: The author used principal square root. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242711/is-it-wrong-to-say-that-100-is-solution-of-sqrt-x10-0 for more information.

Comment: ^Okay I got what you're asking for I'll check it out now.

Comment: I think it's only justified if $x$ is restricted to an interval where $\cos x$ is positive.

Comment: @user232456 Check the original question, I don't think indefinite integrals are restricted to some interval.