# A simple question about nonnegativity of square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals

Say I have a sequence $(x_n)$ and also that $x_n \geq 0 $. Let $x = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. I also know that $x \geq 0$. My question is,

1. Is $\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}$ a nonnegative quantity? I believe this is so because the square root operator returns the principal (nonnegative root)? Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You are taking the absolute value. Even if you don't take the absolute value, then also it is correct, as for any $a\ge 0\implies \sqrt{a}\ge 0$.

Comment: Yes your reasoning is correct. The square root operator returns the principal (non-negative) root.

Comment: Also: [Can the square root of a real number be negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809424/42969).

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad just edited realizing that! Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @MartinR in both content and sentiment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b \ge 0$, then $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b} \ge 0$ hence $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} \ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes your reasoning is correct. The square root operator returns the principal (non-negative) root.